# Sql DB Driven Web Application architecture question

Tags: mysql, database-design, web-applications, architecture, nosql

I'm building medium sized business web application, data is being saved on a MySQL database.

I'm trying to think of a way of adding certain selectable "widgets" to that application (e.g. a currency widget - which will show user specified currencies when the web app is visible) but having an hard time deciding how to save the widget data and settings per user since the widgets do not have a common base.

For example, the currency widget's settings is totally different than say, a weather widget.
One will require a list of desired currencies, and one would require the weather's target location.

I thought of solving the above by keeping all the widget's settings data encoded in the "widgetData" column of a db table which will contain the userId, widgetId and widgetData.
I chose JSON as my way of encoding, and each time a user tries to load it's page, I have to decode it's settings and hand the user the desired data based on the settings.

The same is true for saving the widget's actual data which does not have a common base itself.

Hopefully I can solve this by using a NO-SQL data structure next time, but this is not the case for the current project.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The [Entity Attribute Value database model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) would be useful very to you in this scenario.

It's much more flexible than JSON or XML or other types of formats because it works within your standard SQL data storage, albeit in a different manner.

Answer (score 1):

I voted up the EAV solution because this is one of the valid reasons for using it, but don't fall in love with it.  An advantage of EAV is that it is database-native to the extent that you can write queries in SQL to query it (find me all widgets missing some setting and then add it), while most engines do not have JSON support.

On the other hand, if you want/need to query within a column which contains structured data, XML is a better option than JSON (right now): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue

Answer (score 0):

If your widgets are rendered via Javascript in the browser, then your solution is perfectly fine. Your `widgetData` remains a JSON string, in Javascript you use `JSON.parse()` to turn it into an object and render it, and `JSON.stringify()` to turn it back into a string before posting it back to your server.